# In Android, what is similar with UI view of IOS?

Tags: android

In IOS, an image which can moved is attached like a magnet to a place to a place. I don't know what is like those method in android.

Comment: What kind of view is the image meant to be in?

Comment: I don't know exactly... :)

Answer (score 0):

With an Activity you have a layout file. In that layout file you have multiple items that represent your view. The top most item is what is the same as UIView. You can give this layout an id like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/uiview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
```

---

**Edit**

Today we also have `ConstraintLayout`, which is like `RelativeLayout` but uses constraints (like iOS) to layout its childs. You can look here for more information: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: You want to say RelativeLayout can use like UIview... Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah but it could also be LinearLayout or FrameLayout or any other layout. Then it is like UIView.

Comment: I think this is one hell of a overkill

Comment: @J.Doe why is `RelativeLayout` overkill? He asked what is similar to a UIView in Android. While there is nothing that really is similar to UIView, `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout` probably feels the most similar.